# Determining belonging to a subject

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have some text data from a twitter account. The tweets contain numbers referring to how many people are in a particular area of the gym (usually the weight room and the cardio area).

I'd like to extract the number of people in the weight room, but the problem is that the text is rarely in a standard form.  Some examples include:

```
81 WR 21 CM

Weight room is looking busy with 121 people, while cardio has only 20!

WR:200 CM:50
```

I could probably enumerate all the ways that the account can refer to the weight room, but I need a way to determine which number belongs to which area.

Can spacy perform some measure of semantic belonging?  Could anyone refer me to a resource, or suggest reframing the problem in a new perspective?

Comment: gensim and nltk for starters

Comment: @ShpielMeister yea, there are plenty of NLP tools out there, but I am looking for a perspective or approach to the problem rather than a toolset.

Answer (score 0):

Weight room is looking busy with 121 people, while cardio has only 20!

This would a supervised technique.
1) Use spacy for tags and dependency tree. 
2) Prepare a CRF++ based parser on top of it.

https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/

Comment: Great, I'll try that.